# "body {background-color}" works in HTML but not in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-color

Am able to set the background-color attribute for HTML body in an inline `<style>` command
but not when the identical command is moved to an external stylesheet.  A specific example
is given below.

In test1.html, background-color is set to "blue: in the HTML.  File test2.html is identical to test1.html except the `<style>` command is commented out.  File style.css contains a spec for background-color and also for the `<H1>` element (to test that the browser really is 
reading the stylesheet).

First test produces orange text against a blue background.  Second test produces orange
text, but against a white background.  I've tried this on Firefox 21, Chrome 19, and 
IE 9; all give the same results.

What's going on?  Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the three sample files:

test1.html:

```
<HTML>
<head> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
<style type="text/css">
  body {background-color: blue}
</style> 
</head>
<body> <h1>This is a test.</h1> </body> </html>
```

test2.html:

```
<HTML>
<head> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
<!-- <style type="text/css">
       body {background-color: blue} 
     </style> -->
</head>
<body> <h1>This is a test.</h1> </body> </html>
```

style.css:

```
<style type="text/css">
   body {background-color: green;}
   h1 {color: orange; }
</style>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have HTML tags in your `style.css` file?  Maybe taking those out will fix the issue?

Comment: Is the css file located in the same directory/location as your html file? Remove the tags from you CSS stylesheet as well.

Comment: Your first step in solving an HTML or CSS problem should be to validate both documents.

Answer (score 15):

don't use `<style type="text/css"></style>` in style.css

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

is html tags, and you shouldnt have them in your .css file,

replace the code within style.css with this. Just copy and paste.

```
   body {background-color: green;}
   h1 {color: orange; }
```