# body background does not work

Tags: html, css

my body background color doesn't work.. the path to css is correct. I can't figure out why... PLEASE HELP!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WELCOME PAGE</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>

<div id="box1">
    <div id="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="logregis">
    <a href="login.html"> LOGIN </a> <br>
    or <br>
    <a href="register.html"> REGISTER </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
<style>
body{   background-color:#F00;}
</style>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized and is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: The downvoting is a little excessive.  There is a syntax error in the .css file.  This is a mistake that any beginner, working from code examples, could easily make and a valid question.

Comment: @EricJ. I agree with the downvoting, however the question is hardly useful to any future visitors; if it's not invalid, it's pointless.

Comment: I disagree that it would not help future visitors, because there is a nearly identical question that, if the OP had found, could have answered *his* question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280880/body-background-color-works-in-html-but-not-in-css?rq=1  Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

HTML does not belong in a CSS file:

```
<style>
body{   background-color:#F00;}
</style>
```

should just be:

```
body{   background-color:#F00;}
```